# nokogiri screen scrape css selector issue

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm trying to get css working on this rake task.

```
namespace :task do
  task test: :environment do
    ticketmaster_url = "http://www.ticketmaster.co.uk/derren-brown-miracle-glasgow-04-07-2016/event/370050789149169E?artistid=1408737&majorcatid=10002&minorcatid=53&tpab=-1"
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(ticketmaster_url))
    #psec-p label

    doc.css("#psec-p").each do |price|
      puts price.at_css("#psec-p")
      byebug
    end
  end
end
```

However i'm returning this:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd226469e60 name="fieldset" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd2281c953c name="class" value="group-price widget-group">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd2281c9528 name="id" value="psec-p">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd2281c8d44 "\n            ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd2281c8c7c name="legend" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd2281c8c18 name="id" value="psec-p-legend">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd2281c8614 "Price:">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd2281c8448 "\n          ">]>
```

I'm guessing i selected the wrong element as i have chosen `psec-p`

Could someone let me know where i'm going wrong?

I've been following the railscast 190

Answer (score 0):

The prices on http://www.ticketmaster.co.uk are applied to the HTML dynamically, via Javascript.  This is partially done to hinder scraping efforts.  You really cannot use Nokogiri to scrape this type of content from this domain, as Nokogiri processes raw HTML/XML, and does not execute Javascript in the process.  Other tools exist to do this, but those would require an entirely different approach.

For learning purposes, you should choose a less dynamic site.  For instance, http://www.wallacesuk.com has a nice, parseable site.  You could easily learn basic web scraping techniques with a site that presents information inline with the page, such as this.

Scraping from http://ticketmaster.co.uk would require advanced scraping techniques, well beyond what Railscast 190 is demonstrating.

Comment: Except i wanted a challenge, i've been using ticketmaster as a base for all my learning :) I've also managed to do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
doc.css("#psec-p").each do |price|
  puts price.at_css("#psec-p")
  byebug
end
```

can be better written using:

```
puts doc.at('#psec-p')
```

`#psec-p` is an ID, which can only occur once in a page, so `at` or `at_css` will find that one occurrence.